# BadCredentialsException expected, but got AccountExpiredException

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring Security to support authentication and authorisation in my application. I've customised a few aspects of the security context, but I don't think this plays a part in my question / issue.

I'm currently using **Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE** and **Spring Security 3.1.3.RELEASE**, but I'm about to update to the latest versions.

I think there is a bug with the `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider$DefaultPreAuthenticationChecks()` inner class that I've just found, described below:

If I try to log in with a user and a bad (incorrect) password, but this user is found in my user repository, and they are either locked, disabled or the account is expired, then Spring Security responds with the `LockedException`, `DisabledException`, or `AccountExpiredException`.

However, from this response, I've just determined that the user exists in the repository and even though I've just guessed the password, and don't yet know if it's right or wrong! Rather, Spring Security should respond primarily with a `BadCredentialsException`, and only if the credentials are authenticated respond with the locked, disabled or account expired exceptions.

Has anyone else seen / reported this behaviour? I've searched but couldn't see this anywhere!

Thanks
Rob

### Edit

I've just upgraded to **Spring 3.2.1.RELEASE** and **Spring Security 3.2.0.M1** and this behaviour still remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

This would only be a problem if the exception's message made it into the HTTP response. Ispecting the code shows that it's not the case if you use the default namespace configuration (`<security:form-login>`), because all an attacker gets as response is a HTTP redirect to the login page, regardless of what kind of `AuthenticationException` were thrown on the server side.

Reading the code shows however that it is possible to configure the `AuthenticationFailureHandler` in a way that results in the exposure of this information.
Snippet from `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure()`:

```
    if (defaultFailureUrl == null) {
        logger.debug("No failure URL set, sending 401 Unauthorized error");

        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
           "Authentication Failed: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
```

If you meant this problem then I think you are kind of right, because sending back the exception message is definitely more than the client side should see. Although the developer has to make some effort to achive this insecure behavior, which is setting the `defaultFailureUrl` to null. If I'm not mistaken, this is not even possible by purely using the namespace configuration (there is a default if it's not explicitly set).

Comment: Thanks Zagyi. This is true, but in my application I want to redirect the user back to the login page AND display a relevant error based on the type of `AuthenticationException`. I'm using the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` and setting pages based on the exception received. I think this is a fairly standard approach to using the `AuthenticationFailureHandler`. While I agree that the developer has to make some effort to expose this vulnerability, I think the effort being made is fairly standard practise!. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, alright I got it. :) If you want to inform the user about the different `AccountStatusException`s, but only in case the presented credentials are acceptable, then you have a problem. The library authors regularly answer questions here, but it might be easier to grab their attention with a JIRA ticket, and this issue warrants a ticket I suppose.

Comment: Just as a side note: I guess the `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` is better for your use-case than the `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I am indeed using the `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` for this. I'll update with reference to the JIRA ticket when I've posted one. Thanks for your responses Zagyi.